# Is there any way to access this text using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium to evaluate the accuracy of chess moves within my dataset of games for an AI. So far, I can access the evaluation bar, but not the FEN (it returns an empty string). Is there any way to access the FEN within [this site](https://www.365chess.com/analysis_board.php).

This is the textbox: [image]

I want to grab this: `rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3p4/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq d6 0 2`

This is the HTML of the textbox:

```html
<input type="text" readonly="" class="text" id="fen_position" name="fen_position" value="" style="width:350px;font-size: 0.7em !important;padding: 3px 6px !important;">
```

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.headless = True

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://www.365chess.com/analysis_board.php")

browser.implicitly_wait(5); fen = browser.find_element_by_id('fen_position').text
print(fen)
```

Comment: I think it also shows it in the script. However, I am not sure how to access it that way using selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the FEN is an `<input>` for inputs the value is stored as a "value" in properties you can use the .get_property("value") to access it. Here is the working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.headless = True

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://www.365chess.com/analysis_board.php")

browser.implicitly_wait(5); fen = browser.find_element_by_id('fen_position').get_property("value")
print(fen)
```

Happy coding :)